# DIV background image is not 100% on a smartphone

Tags: html, css, responsive-design, media-queries

I have developed a small website - luxorclub.ru/en. In "Menu" section there's bottles image which is supposed to be 100% with repeat-x. It looks good on desktop but it's not 100% on a smartphone.

This is how it looks on a desktop

[image]

And this is how it looks on Galaxy S6

[image]

CSS:

```
#outer-menu-food {
    width: 100%;
    height: 700px;
    background: url('images/menu/menu-bg3.png') repeat-x;
    background-position: center;
}
```

Comment: what happens if you set height to auto for mobile?

Comment: @jakob   Nothing happened. It's `height:auto;` now.

Comment: what about `background-size:cover;`?

Comment: @jakob `background-size:cover;` didn't help either.

Comment: then some other css is messing with it.. make jsfiddle with full code.. because this one should work as it is.. check test here where it works with your code https://jsfiddle.net/Luc8kv09/

Comment: The results will change depending on which browser you are using on both desktop or mobile, as each browser has vaious "default" values for HTML elements such as a `<body>` margin etc.

Answer (score 0):

This is because the #outer-menu-food take the width of the viewport and background will stretch only to that point. You might have to restructure everything for your website to display properly on mobile. Like after a particular resolution remove the fixed values you give as width and stuff and consider giving it percentage values.

In short write [media queries](http://www.w3schools.com/css/css_rwd_mediaqueries.asp) to get things fixed on mobile device.